# Listado de medallas en SOes

Tags: característica-nueva, preguntas

donde puedo ver los detalles de cada **medalla** y como poder saber que debe de hacer para ganarme cada una de ellas?. Pues estoy aprendiendo derricien a usar esta plataforma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes acceder a la siguiente [url](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) donde te van a aparecer listadas cada una de ellas, indicando este orden:

- La categoría a la cual pertenecen
- Nombre de la medalla
- Descripción
- El número de veces que ha sido otorgada a los miembros de la comunidad

En la parte superior, las vas a tener agrupadas por:

- Todas: El listado general de medallas disponibles y que puedes obtener
- Ganadas: Aquellas que por acciones de:

  - Moderación
  - Votación
  - Preguntas
  - Respuestas
  - Atención a las colas de revisión
  - Por puntaje en las distintas etiquetas de lenguajes o tecnologìas que al momento existen
- Sin ganar, las cuales también cuentan con una categoría, una descripción donde se establece lo que se debe lograr para conseguirlas

Finalmente tienes ahí mismo 3 pestañas divididas por:

- Oro
- Plata
- Bronce

Cada una de las anterior también tienen:

- Nombre
- Descripción de como ganarlas
- El número de veces que ha sido otrorgada a miembros de la comunidad